# Не переходит на новую строку в файле

Tags: python

Думаю,что может быть уже второй час,но не могу понять.

Вот задача:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что выводит:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на скачку файла:https://stepik.org/api/attempts/221010356/file(не знаю ли скачает)

Вот код:

```
with open("c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Downloads\\dataset_3363_4.txt") as text:
    lists=text.readlines()
def mean(x):
    i, n = 0, 0
    for _ in x:
        i+=int(_)
        n+=1
    return i/n
math,phy,rus=[],[],[]
for table in lists:
    table=table.strip().split(";")
    table.remove(table[0])
    math.append(table[0])
    phy.append(table[1])
    rus.append(table[2])
    with open("c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Downloads\\dataset_3363_4.txt","w+") as text:
        text.write(str(mean(table))+"\n")
with open("c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Downloads\\dataset_3363_4.txt","w+") as text:
    ari=[str(mean(math)),str(mean(phy)),str(mean(rus))]
    ari=" ".join(ari)
    text.write(ari)
```

Comment: Вы хотите построчно вывести список в файл? `text.write('\n'.join(ari))`?

Comment: @вася мне нужно только построчно выводить средние балы

Comment: `text.write(str(mean(table))+"\n")` уже добавляет перевод строки

Comment: @вася я тоже так думал и не мог понять в чем проблема

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for table in lists:
  with open("c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Downloads\\dataset_3363_4.txt","w+") as text:
            text.write(str(mean(table))+"\n")
```

Перевожу на русский. В **цикле** (!!!)  - открыли файл в режиме "w+", записали в него что-то, закрыли. На второй час думания можно вспомнить, что "w+" всегда ПЕРЕЗАПИСЫВАЕТ (а не ДОПИСЫВАЕТ) файл . И понимаем, что выводит он вам всегда последнюю запись. Стирая все предыдущие. Короче, меняйте "w+" на "a+"

Comment: а где там закрытие ? 3 открытия вроде только

Comment: Благослови тебя Бог

Comment: @Интик повтороное открытие (с использованием менеджера контекста) = закрытие+ открытие